# probable differences using FPGA UCLINUX SOCKET and Python socket

Tags: sockets, fpga, uclinux

I am working on altera FPGA and have written a client application on uclinux. I have also written server client application in Python. My FPGA Client is able to connect with Python server but it is unable to connect when server is placed on a remote location passing more than one router.

If any one having idea where the probable mistake is and ways to debug the issue

Comment: Do you have any kind of timeout inside your FPGA? This is not really an FPGA question, but a question about uCLinux.

Comment: Can some more typical system, substituted on the same network cable, connect?